# How to avoid the same name of namespace and class in C#?

Tags: c#, naming

> I knew it is recommended to **use different names** in class and namespace, but sometimes it is hard to achieve it. **It is easier said than done.** They never give us a solution when we need to use the same name because of a certain case.

**For example**, I need a namespace in which to locate all the classes about configuration, so the namespace is named *ABC.Configuration*. I don't think there is anything wrong with this name.

And under the namespace I need a class to store the configuration, so its name will also be *Configuration*. Reasonable, don't you think?

Besides I have some other classes such as ConfigurationBuilder, ConfigurationManager, etc, under the namespace.

What's more in Java, the package name we use *"camelCase"*, and the class name we use *"PascalCase"*. So because of the case of naming, there is no problem.

So how to name the classes in this scenario in C#？

---

Thank you very much. If I use Configuration.Configuration, I need to write more only because of naming while others are just ConfigurationManager without the namespace. It's a little bit mess.

The idea to use ConfigurationStore is a good one, thank you. 
I think the solution to name a class is to identify the usage clearly in the name and add another word. 
But in my project, I need to use the Configuration somewhere, if I write ConfigurationStore.Path to read the configuration, it looks strange.
Maybe I can use a interface like IConfiguration to avoid the naming problem

Comment: You can have a type `Configuration.Configuration`. Nothing prevents you from doing that.

Comment: C# allows naming in all lowercase (`configuration.configuration`) but `PascalCase` is more recommended for namespaces, classes & methods naming convention.

Comment: I tried to use lowercase. But it was a mess, because all other libraries are PascalCase.

Answer (score 5):

You could name your namespace `ConfigurationManagement`. Or name your class `ConfigurationStore` if it stores configurations.

camelCase vs PascalCase: The same tools that tell you naming your namespace like a class is bad, will tell you that entities who's name differs only in capitalization are bad, too.

So find better names.

Comment: Or `UsersSystem` / `UsersDomain` when you have a static class `Users`.

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly ok to use the same name for the namespace and class. You can refer to your `Configuration` class as `Configuration.Configuration` or `Configuration` if you have a `using` directive. There is no confusion.

If it is just your personal preference that you don't like to have a class with the same name as the namespace, here are some other names for configuration:

- `Config`
- `Configurations`
- `Configs`
- `ConfigurationManager` (class name only)

Also, IDEs will probably tell you what an identifier refers to by having different icons. For example in Xamarin Studio:

[image]

Namespaces are marked with `{`s while classes are marked with `C`s.

Comment: You compiler will choke on it in a few special scenarios. Just saying. It's perfectly legal... until you hit that point. Then it's a pain in certain a body part. It's easier to do it right the first time, especially if you publish NuGet packages for others to use, because *they* will have the problem and no option to change it easily.

Comment: That's why I pointed out that he IIDE will tell you what an identifier is referring to in case the compiler complains, so that the OP can figure out what is going on. @nvoigt

Comment: I don't want to use different alias or abbr. for one meaning in a project. If I decided to use Config at one place, then anywhere  will be Config

Answer (score 0):

In C# PascalCase is used in both scenarios. For namespaces and for classes if I'm not wrong about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why have ABC.Configuration when you can just have ABC? I mean, it will be a bit confusing not to mention long names. ABC.Configuration.Configuration, to access the Configuration class, as opposed to ABC.Configuration. I would rather apply the latter.

Comment: If I only have one class, I will do this. What about other classes? Put ConfigurationManager, ConfigurationBuilder all in ABC? It will be a mess, don't you think?

Comment: @HalfLegend But how many configuration types will be there? Three? A namespace for just three types seems a bit too much, not to mention that such a namespace will likely *never* get expanded later.

Comment: Not exactly. Look at the System.Configuration, for instance. It has all kinds of Configuration classes or methods. Above all, it's up to you what to name it. My counsel to you is to try to keep them small.